# Cannot read setMap property of undefined while using Google maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I call the initialize function on page load. Which correctly setsup all the markers. Then I have a searchbox along with a submit button which clears all the markers and then fetches a new JSON object which consist of new markers to be created. As soon as I enter a search query and call the getWorldTweets function I get this error:

Cannot read setMap property of undefined

which points to the addMarker and deleteMarker functions.

```
var map;
var marker;
var allmarkers = [];
var iterator = 0;
var riterator = 0;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var search = {
  q: ""
};
function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
      //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
      zoom: 2,
      //draggable: false,
      minZoom: 1
    };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
getWorldTweets();
}

function getWorldTweets(){
  deleteMarkers();
  iterator = 0;
  riterator = 0;
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/worldTweetsDatabaseHandler.php',
        data: search,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function( res ) {
          console.log(res);
          for(var x in res){
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(res[x]['LATITUDE'],res[x]['LONGITUDE']);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: "img/tweetmarker2.png",
            position: myLatlng,
            title: res[x]['TWEET_TEXT']
            });
            allmarkers.push(marker); 
          }
          setMarkersMap();
        }
    });
}

function addMarker(){
  allmarkers[iterator].setMap(map);
  iterator++;
}
function deleteMarker(){
  allmarkers[riterator].setMap(null);
  riterator++;
}

function setMarkersMap(){
  for(var i = 0;i<allmarkers.length;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      addMarker();
    },i*100);
    setTimeout(function(){
      deleteMarker();
    },i*500);
  }
}


function setAllMap(map){
  for(var i = 0;i<allmarkers.length;i++){
    //console.log("hello");
    allmarkers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}

function clearMarkers() {
  setAllMap(null);
}

function deleteMarkers() {
  console.log("in delete");
  clearMarkers();
  allmarkers = [];
}

$("#submit").on("click", function () { 
  search.q=document.getElementById('searchquery').value;
  //deleteMarkers();
  getWorldTweets(); 
});

$("#searchquery").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#submit").click();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: `setMarkersMap` - you're looping over your markers, adding them, then deleting them?  Can you explain what's going on here

Comment: So as there are a lot of markers on the map, I am adding the markers at a faster rate then deleting the oldest ones at a slower rate.

Comment: you're going to get problems there I think of deleting and adding to and from the same array

Comment: What kind of problems ? Could you give an example ? As of now that is working fine.

Comment: you call addMarker every 100 milliseconds, and deleteMarker every 500 milliseconds.  How many markers are you dealing with?  If there's 5 for instance, you'll call both addMarker and deleteMarker at the same time.  The global variable `allmarkers` is going to get messed up

Comment: You are right, but don't `addMarker` and `deleteMarker` use different iterators ?

Comment: Iterator and riterator both start at zero, and get incremented. Sooner or later you're going to get conflicts with markers disappearing

Comment: So how do you suggest I separate it ?

Answer (score 0):

After you add all your markers, the global variable `iterator` holds the index of your latest marker.

If at any given point you want to discard your old marker collection and add a new collection, you need to reset `iterator` back to zero, or you will be trying to set the map of an index that's over the length of the `allmarkers` array.

For example

1. Your original getTweets retrieves 100 markers. Your  `allmarkers` array has 100 items
2. You call setMarkersMap() which iterates through the 100 markers of `allmarkers`. `iterator` is set to 100.
3. You retrieve another 100 markers. `allmarkers` is now 200.
4. You call setMarkersMap() to iterate from 0 to 200. `iterator` is already at 100, will try to go up to 300. At marker 201 it will try to operate on a non existant index of `allmarkers`

There are several ways you can go here:

- Don't try to operate on the new and old markers in one loop. Turn off the old ones, then turn on the new ones.
- If you want to hold the index of the last batch, hence the purpose for global variables, don't iterate from 0 to `allmarkers.length`, but instead from `iterator` to `allmarkers.length`.
- If you won't ever need an old batch of markers, don't just set their map to null. Get them out of your array

.

```
while(allmarkers.length) {
  var oldMarker=allmarkers.pop();
  oldMarker.setMap(null);
  // delete oldMarker;  // optionally delete it, allegedly it's unnnecesary.
}
```

if you do the latter, then you'll always operate on a 0-100 batch.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply @amenadiel . In the `deleteMarkers` function I am clearing the array `allmarkers`. Also, I am calling the `deleteMarkers` in the `getWorldTweets` function. So when new tweets are retrieved `allmarkers` is emptied, `iterator` and `riterator` is all set to 0.

Comment: You're right, I missed that resetting. Perhaps you could `console.log(allmarkers[iterator]);` to check there's an actual marker in that position of the array

Comment: So I put `console.log(iterator);console.log(allmarkers[iterator]);` in the `addmarker` method. It perfectly iterates through the size of the allmarkers but then it doesn't stop there. It keeps on going forward so I get errors like this `35 Sn {gm_accessors_: Object, animation: 2, gm_bindings_: Object, icon: "img/tweetmarker2.png", position: kf…} 
36 Sn {gm_accessors_: Object, animation: 2, gm_bindings_: Object, icon: "img/tweetmarker2.png", position: kf…} 
37 undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined` (1/2)

Comment: `37 undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined
37 undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined
37 undefined Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined` (2/2)

Comment: I guess you could verify that allmarkers[iterator] is different from undefined...

Comment: Meaning ? The error points to the same line number of the line containing `allmarkers[iterator].setMap(map);` .

Comment: I mean you could trap the error before it happens, and only use marker methods if it's a valid one

Comment: Yes. That seems like a decent solution but it doesn't seem to find the root of the problem.